# Importing JSON file in ReactXP

Tags: json, typescript, reactxp

I have strange problem possibly bug with importing JSON file as object into my application. I do have:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
}
```

Looking at the s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶  source maps JSON is being imported and even when I look at debugger:
[image]

But as you see debugger is able to see contents of this var/JSON while app claims it's undefined. Can it be building cache problem?
I import JSON file like:

```
import  * as eventsDB from './events.json';
```

and for debugging purpose I export it like this:

```
export const jsonDB = eventsDB;
```

EDIT: After checking carefuly build whole reducer where I import and export JSON was ommited but for some reason everything was in Source-Maps, I'm currently searching for possible reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I've located the problem. I think this might be helpful, so I want to share the solution. As I said in reducer named events (file name events.ts) I've imported the JSON:

```
import  * as eventsDB from './events.json';
```

And some of you might already noticed the problem. Even when I included the extension, for some reason there was name conflict so under events reducer

```
import  events from '../reducers/events';
```

I actually had the JSON. And under JSON I had undefined. Still the mistery is why debugger saw the contents of the variable correctly.